# Document file won't save properly

Tags: c#, multithreading, com, ms-word

I have a script that creates files on multiple threads.   Occassionally, I will get the following error on the document.SaveAs() call:

> {"Word cannot save or create this file. Make sure that the disk you
>   want to save the file on is not full, write-protected, or damaged.\r
>   (C:\...\fileName.docx)"}

This is maddening because it seems to happen sometimes and not others.  I've been spending the last day trying to figure it out, and have made very little progress. One thing I have ruled out is the possibility of more than one thread trying to create the same file.  I am certain this isn't happening.   Is there anything I'm missing in my code that would be causing this, or is this just a fact of life when working with com objects? I'm doing exactly what code tutorials out there are saying, maybe I should abandon using multiple threads?

```
BuildDocumentsThread(){
        var word = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
        word.Options.CreateBackup = false;
        var wordQuit = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Application)word;

        foreach(var value in values){
            FormBuilder.BuildSummaryForm(word, value);
        }

        wordQuit.Quit();
}

public static void BuildSummaryForm(Application word, string value) {
        var summaryFormPath = Utilities.GetSummaryFilePath(value);

        if (File.Exists(summaryFormPath))
            File.Delete(summaryFormPath);

        object path = summaryFormPath;
        object readOnly = false;
        object o = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        var document = word.Documents.Add(ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o);
        document.Activate();

        Paragraph p1 = document.Content.Paragraphs.Add(ref o);
        p1.Range.Font.Name = "Arial";
        p1.Range.Font.Size = 10;
        p1.Range.Text = value;

        document.SaveAs(ref path, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o);
        document.Close();
}
```

Comment: The SaveAs method is not thread safe (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.documentclass.saveas(v=office.11).aspx).  Also, if the file is being saved or opened by another process, you will probably hit this error.

Comment: first thing i must ask: you don't have MS Word open while running this app do you?

Comment: @JohnKoerner, by not thread safe, does that mean that it should never be used with multiple threads? I don't understand what the page means when it says: "Any public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are thread safe." Also, I know for a fact only one thread is accessing a single file at a time.

Comment: @ardnew, no, I have no instances of MS word running when this happens.  I even clear out any processes named WINWORD and I still get this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the SaveAs is not thread safe as describe by John Koerner in the comment, you could try to lock the SaveAs and Close.

In this case I'm mot sure the multithreading process will be usefull anymore, but it's worst a try. At least you will know if your error is coming from the SaveAs function.

---

To add some infromation following your comment:

add a class variable to create the lock

```
private static object _savelock = new object();
```

Then in you worker:

```
lock(_savelock)
{
   document.SaveAs(ref path, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o);
}
document.Close();
```

In this case, no save operation will be done at the same time. Locking the close as well may be necessary

- 1 thread take the lock and do the save
- In the meantime 2 thread try to do a save but wait until the previous thread finish the save and release the lock

In this case you don't really care if it's the same instance of word or not. in both case it will work.

The main drawback is that if the save operation take 95% of the time of the thread, multi threading become nearly useless because by locking the save operation, only 5% of the process is really multi threaded. However if "freeing" the ui and let the user continue working while the process is running is the aim, it's a viable solution.

Check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx for the lock pricinple

Comment: Can you help me understand this?  Let's say I use only one instance of word, and send that to each thread as an argument.  If I lock word in any thread, will that instance of word lock in every other thread, or does each thread create a copy of the instance of word once it starts?

Comment: This is a very helpful post.  I'm currently testing the script that tries to save it and if it fails, it locks the object and then tries saving.  As long as this works, I'll still get the speed benefit of using multiple threads, and have the lock for when the save fails.